# HTML Form value for one input not being picked up in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an HTML form that I am trying to validate with Regex in JavaScript.  It currently is working for the input="text" fields firstName and lastName.  However, it will not work for the input="text" field gender.

I have been looking at this for an hour and cannot seem to figure out why.

```js
function validate() {

  var form = document.forms['formIt'];

  var counter = 0;

  if (!form.firstName.value.match(/^[A-Z][a-z]*$/)) {
    generateMessage("Please capitalize the first letter and assure only letters are entered", "fName", "red");

  } else {
    counter++;
  }

  if (!form.lastName.value.match(/^[A-Z][a-z]*$/)) {
    generateMessage("Please capitalize the first letter and assure only letters are entered", "lName", "red");

  } else {
    counter++;
  }

  if (!form.gender.value.match(/^[A-Z]/)) {
    generateMessage("Gender", "gen", "red");
  }


  if (counter === 3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Form for Updating -->
<form id="formIt" name="formIt" method="post" action="updatedIt.php">
  <p>
    <label>Employee No.:  <input type="text"  name="empNum" id="empNum" 
    value="<?php echo $iD ?>" readonly/> </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Birth Date:  <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" 
    value="<?php echo $birthday ?>" /></label> <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="target" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>First Name:  <input type="text" onkeyup="validateName()" 
    name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName ?>"  />
    <span id="fName"></span></label> <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="target2" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Last Name:  <input type="text" onkeyup="validateName()" 
    name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastName ?>" />
    <span id="lName"></span></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="target3" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Gender:  <input type="text" onkeyup="validateName()" 
    name="gender" id="gender" value="<?php echo $gender ?>" />
    <span id="gen"></span></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="target4" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Hire Date:  <input type="date" name="hiredate" id="hiredate" 
    value="<?php echo $hired ?>" /></label> <br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="target5" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label><input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" 
    value="Submit" onclick="return validate()"/> </label> <br />
  </p>
</form>
```

I am getting an "Unresolved variable" error for gender in this line:

```
if(!form.gender.value.match(/^[A-Z]/)){
```

It is the same input type as firstName and lastName, I do not understand why it is giving me this error.  I've tried moving the gender form input to a differnt place in the form, tried naming it something else, and tried getting the value of it by elementId in JS, nothing is working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please use the snippet `<>` tool to create [mcve] with tidy code.

Comment: Side note: If you're just testing for match/no match, `.test` is better than `.match` as it doesn't have to do as much work (and is clearer semantically). Also note that your `if/else` at the end can, and should, just be `return counter === 3;`

Comment: var form = document.forms['formIt']; seems incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte — In what way does that seem incorrect?

Comment: my bad, misread it. The ID attribute seems a little redundant then.. ?

Comment: You function name is 'validate' yet you call 'validateName' from your onkeyup events

Comment: Input elements shouldn't be inside label, and there're missing semicolons in all php statements. Is this the actual code or n example?

Comment: @pokeybit that is a separate function that is working fine.  I only included the one that is causing the error.

Comment: @MarioZ I made your suggested changes, it seems like the JS is running the validation on it (as I get the red Gender notifier in the span when I mess it up to not match the regex) but it still shows the unresolved variable error

Comment: I would try renaming the gender field, or create a new one may and be call a function instead with bunch of if statements to check for gender instead of regex, something may be caching.